# How to append file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file a.txt and I have file b.txt.I am reading both the file.

Lets assume a.txt has:

```
Apple is a fruit.
I like java.
I am an human being.
I am saying hello world.
```

Lets say b.txt has

```
I am the planet earth
```

Now i am trying to search for particular string in a.txt eg:I am human being.If i find this line .I want to append the content in b.txt to a.txt.My output file should look some thing like this

```
Apple is a fruit.
I like java.
I am the planet earth---->appended
I am an human being.
I am saying hello world.
```

I am trying below but its not helping

```
open (FILE1 , "a.txt")
my (@fpointer1) = <FILE>; 
close FILE1

open (FILE2 , "b.txt")
my (@fpointer1) = <FILE>; 
close FILE2

#Open the a.txt again, but this time in write mode
open (FILE3 , ">a.txt")
my (@fpointer1) = <FILE>; 
close FILE3

foreach $line (@fpointer1) {

if (line to be searched is found)
--> Paste(Insert) the contents of file "b.txt" read through fpointer2

}
```

Comment: This is not valid perl. You are missing `;` after most expressions. Always start your files with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Also you should use the three-argument-version of `open` and lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather quick and dirty working example:

```
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open FILE, "a.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; 
while (<FILE>){
$string_A .= $_;
}

open FILE, "b.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; 
while (<FILE>){
$string_B .= $_;
}
close FILE;

$searchString = "I am an human being.";


$resultPosition = index($string_A, $searchString);

if($resultPosition!= -1){

$endPosition = length($string_A)+length($string_B)-length($searchString);

$temp_String  =  substr($string_A, 0, $resultPosition).$string_B." ";


$final_String =$temp_String.substr($string_A, $resultPosition, $endPosition) ;
}
else {print "String not found!";}

print $final_String;
```

There might be more efficient ways of doing it. But you can have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here an Example

```
use strict;

open(A, ">>a.txt") or die "a.txt not open";
open(B, "b.txt") or die "b.txt not open";

my @text = <B>;
foreach my $l (@text){
        if ($l =~ /I am the planet earth/sg){
                print A $&;
        }
}
```

i think, like this......